# clearmake makefil "too many commands" warning, i think i know why but i dont know how to fix it

Tags: makefile

I have a clearmake makefile that builds some .c files in arm mode and some in thumb mode..

imagine several sets of objects:

$(SET1_OBJECTS)

$(SET2_OBJECTS)

$(SET3_OBJECTS)

and

$(THUMB_MODE_OBJECTS)

now, later in the makefile I have the following:

```
.c.o:
    @$(ECHO) "Compiling $<"
    @$(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) <

$(THUMB_MODE_OBJECTS): $${@:.o=.c}
    @$(ECHO) "Thumb Compiling $<"
    @$(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(THUMB_CCFLAGS) $<
```

As you can see, the difference is the thumb flags.. .. but when i build i get these warnings:

clearmake: Warning: Too many command lines for "foo.o"

The warnings come from all of the files that are part of the THUMB_MODE_OBJECTS list, it seems clearmake thinks it has 2 commands because it also meets the .c.o:

Is there a way to change .c.o: to be "anything not $(THUMB_MODE_OBJECTS)" ??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: FYI the third line should be  `@$(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<` can you please post the output verbose?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, i do have a $<  i did a -d for full debug data but it doesn't show anything interesting..

Comment: +---- Starting clean
>>> 22:04:12.35983459344188131 (clearmake): Processing description file "I:\project\objects\Makefile.options.release"
Processing build options from:
I:\project\objects\Makefile.options
>>> 22:04:12.36022096869982993 (clearmake): Processing description file "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\etc\builtin.mk"
>>> 22:04:12.36022096869983060 (clearmake): Processing description file "makefile"
clearmake: Warning: Too many command lines for "foo.o"

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264244 you can see is there are two targets with different dependency, try to remove it out. check what `$(THUMB_MODE_OBJECTS)` expands to